# References not found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reference, project, solution

I have multiple projects in my solution and currently I am experiencing a very weird problem:

I have project A - rebuildable with no error.
I have project B referencing project A - also rebuildable with no error.
But when i try to rebuild all, the whole solution with othre projects except A and B it gives me errors:

> ```
> Error 31  The type or namespace name 'Something' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> ```

And errors are not just in projects A or B, but all over the solution..

but when I comment in project B all the objects created from classes from project A ( and the project A is still referenced in project B) - it all works.

Any idea what may be causing such a strange problem?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RM click on your Project -> Add Reference...

find your `DLL`

*Updated:*

you should change your `.Net Framework 4 Client Profile` to `.Net Framework 4`

Comment: the projects are all references, altough it is weird the problem with missing assemblies is always with referenced projects ( Project -> add reference -> project ->select project )

Comment: it helped! thank you very much sir:) Is there any reason why use Client Profile? Whats the difference anyway?

Comment: @JohnSmith to your second comment question. As the name said its for client application. In a short - can less, run with some more speed.