# References causing namespace not found

Tags: c#, .net, vs-community-edition

In my solution I needed to add a project from a previous app (Utils). I created a new copy of the app in the root folder of my new solution and added it to the solution using Add->Existing Project. After that I referenced the new project, so that I could use it's methods within another part of the project (Comms), by right clicking the Main project and selecting Add->References and checking the Utils project, this automatically added the reference in the Comms project.

Once I implemented the methods I needed in the Main project I got the error "The type or namespace name "Utils" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" - ONLY for the Comms project and not where I had used Utils in main.

However, I checked what I had done and everything seemed in order as shown:

Showing Reference in Comms' References;

[image: Showing Reference in Comms' References]

Showing Error;

[image: Showing Error]

Showing Using Directive;

[image: Showing Using Directive]

Next I searched on stack exchange and found [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219107/references-not-found)

It seemed relevant and sure enough the target framework was set to `.Net Framework 4 Client Profile` for the Utils project and `.Net Framework 4.5` in the main project and Comms so I set the target framework to `.Net Framework 4` in all cases as shown;

[image: Showing .Net Framework 4 set as target framework]

I then cleaned and rebuilt my solution and still Comms is not referencing Utils correctly. Please can someone help me.

It may or may not be relevant but this is VS Community 2015

Comment: What type of reference did you use to add the Utils project to the Comms project? Solution? File?

Comment: Does the Utils project actually have public types in the `Utils` namespace? Assembly names and namespace names are only *conventionally* related... It's fine for a .NET 4.5 project to refer to a .NET 4 project, btw...

Comment: Try the classic, restart visual studio, sometimes this solves some strange reference errors

Comment: You've added Utils as a project reference instead of an assembly reference and have 22 other errors, does it build?

Comment: @PaulHunt I am unsure what you mean by that. Simply added the Utils project to the solution by right-clicking the solution Add->Existing Project then selecting the project file. Once that was done I referenced it in the main project by right clicking Main project Add->Reference and clicking the check box in the Project section of the reference manager. The Utils project is then shown in the reference manager of the Comms project also, and it is checked there also This is VS Community 15. I probably should have mentioned that, I will re-tag approppriately.

Comment: @JonSkeet The utils project does have public types and I have used it in previous solutions successfully before.

Comment: @DavidBeaumont I have tried that, also with rebuilding/building/cleaning in various attempts.

Comment: @LewisHeslop: Again, that doesn't mean it has types in the `Utils` namespace...

Comment: @LewisHeslop Did you make sure all your projects target the same .NET?

Comment: @JamesBarrass All of the other errors are in Comms and arise due to the Utils not being being referenced. I'm not sure what impact that will have. The main does not build, for unrelated reasons. As for adding Utils as a project reference instead of an assembly reference, I don't know what you mean by that, I only know of this method of referencing in VS2015 and it has worked in the past.

Comment: @JonSkeet You were right. For some reason the types had dropped out of the Utils namespace.

Comment: @JonSkeet apparently the cs files did not copy over properly!! I should have checked this earlier instead of worrying about my references. References are fickle things in VS and so I assumed it would be something to do with them, the problem was more obvious however. Thanks for pointing it out, I would have overlooked it for hours!!

Comment: All, I have now solved the problem, when copying over the Utils as a project VS had lost access to the .cs files of the Utils project. I moved the files to a more accessible location (i.e. not shared) and added the .cs files. This solved my problem.